# Loading data in existing dataset in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online

In ArcGIS online (AGOL), is it possible to load data (shapefile or geodatabase) into an existing layer? The map layer is shared and editable.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS Online You can bring it into ArcMap and Create Local Copy and merge your data into the local copy and sync that back to the service.

Or if the data you want to merge with the existing service, you first will have to publish the shapefile or feature class up as a feature service in AGOL and then bring both services into a web map and then run the merge GP service (under analysis in the map viewer) which will output a new service.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro gives you the ability to edit features services directly from ArcGIS Online. Check out the documentation [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/overview-of-desktop-editing.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_7767B67C254A4ACE9E9852A7976E6E0A). You could use the [Append tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm) to load your existing data into the ArcGIS Online feature service.

Note that the feature service doesn't have to be shared once you log into your ArcGIS Online account through ArcGIS Pro. Tokens are automatically appended to edits, etc. once you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of python and [ArcREST](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST), specifically [this sample.](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/blob/master/samples/append_fc_to_service.py)
This is useful if you plan on having this as a repeated task and can schedule it to happen perhaps nightly.  However if it is a one off job, Russ answer (1st paragraph) would be my choice.

Pasting here in case link dies:

```
import arcrest, json
from arcresthelper import featureservicetools
from arcresthelper import common
def trace():
    """
        trace finds the line, the filename
        and error message and returns it
        to the user
    """
    import traceback, inspect
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    filename = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
    # script name + line number
    line = tbinfo.split(", ")[1]
    # Get Python syntax error
    #
    synerror = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()[-1]
    return line, filename, synerror

if __name__ == "__main__":

    proxy_port = None
    proxy_url = None

    securityinfo = {}
    securityinfo['security_type'] = 'Portal'#LDAP, NTLM, OAuth, Portal, PKI
    securityinfo['username'] = ""#<UserName>
    securityinfo['password'] = ""#<Password>
    securityinfo['org_url'] = "http://www.arcgis.com"
    securityinfo['proxy_url'] = proxy_url
    securityinfo['proxy_port'] = proxy_port
    securityinfo['referer_url'] = None
    securityinfo['token_url'] = None
    securityinfo['certificatefile'] = None
    securityinfo['keyfile'] = None
    securityinfo['client_id'] = None
    securityinfo['secret_id'] = None


    itemId = ""#<Item ID>
    layerName=''#Name of layer in the service
    fc=r''#Path to Feature Class
    atTable=None
    try:
        fst = featureservicetools.featureservicetools(securityinfo)
        if fst.valid == False:
            print fst.message
        else:

            fs = fst.GetFeatureService(itemId=itemId,returnURLOnly=False)
            if not fs is None:

                fl = fst.GetLayerFromFeatureService(fs=fs,layerName=layerName,returnURLOnly=False)
                if not fl is None:
                    results = fl.addFeatures(fc=fc,attachmentTable=atTable)
                    print json.dumps(results)
                else:
                    print "Layer %s was not found, please check your credentials and layer name" % layerName
            else:
                print "Feature Service with id %s was not found" % fsId

    except:
        line, filename, synerror = trace()
        print "error on line: %s" % line
        print "error in file name: %s" % filename
        print "with error message: %s" % synerror
```